# Does Ludovic Orban (the current Romanian PM) speak Hungarian?

Tags: romania, languages, prime-minister, minorities

According to Wikipedia, [Ludovic Orban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludovic_Orban), the current PM of Romania (and who apparently has [no relationship](https://www.wsj.com/articles/leaders-of-neighboring-countries-share-a-name-confusion-ensues-11573832025) with Hungary's Viktor Orban), is of mixed Hungarian and Romanian ethnicity. Does Ludovic Orban speak Hungarian? Fluently?

(I see that Ludovic's brother [Leonard Orban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Orban) was EU Commissioner for multilingualism, so I suspect the answer to whether Ludovic speaks Hungarian is yes, but oddly I cannot find confirmation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it is rather find the list of foreign languages spoken by the current Romanian PM, Ludovic Orban.

[This article](https://www.mediafax.ro/politic/intalnirea-pnl-udmr-a-inceput-cu-o-poezie-in-limba-maghiara-recitata-de-ludovic-orban-5183455) tells about Ludovic Orban reciting a Hungarian poem before beginning the negotiations with the main Hungarian party in Romania (translated from Romanian):

> Ludovic Orban wanted to recite a poem in Hungarian.
>
> The PNL leader **later translated with the help of Marko Bela the poem**,
>   which provoked the laugh of the UDMR representatives who thought it
>   was "good"

This suggests that his Hungarian is quite rusty.

[Another article](https://www.ziarulevenimentul.ro/stiri/politica/video-biografia-fara-perdea-a-lui-ludovic-orban-premierul-desemnat--217470412.html) suggests that he only knows basic Hungarian  (translated from Romanian):

He speaks English and French (fluent) and German and **Hungarian (basics)**.

Based on this I would say Ludovic Orban speaks only basic Hungarian.

Comment: Indeed it is rather <missing words?> find the lsit …?